# Eclipse Juno Editors side by side gives white bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Eclipse Juno Build id: 20120614-1722, running on Windows XP 64-bit. Using the Classic theme.

Eclipse Juno gets this white bar when I open two editors side by side. Is anyone aware of a fix for this?

[image: Eclipse Juno gets this white bar when I open two editors side by side]

Perhaps answering my own question, this doesn't always happen: after closing and re-opening a couple of times I see it without the white bar.

[image: Doesn't always happen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by closing and opening Eclipse again. This must be an intermittent issue because I haven't been able to reliably re-produce it. It may have been some combination of the perspective I was using, stretching Eclipse over two screens and high memory use.